# How do I read the element from a dropdown menu of a html?

Tags: java, scala, selenium-webdriver

I am parsing the following html by Selenium FirefoxDriver -

```
      <div id="primaryNav" style='background: url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/primaryNavBackground._V161555288_.gif") repeat-x bottom;'> 
       <div id="menuh">
        <ul>
            <li style="visibility:hidden; 
        height:24px"/>


               <li style='background:url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/tab-unslected-right._V161557413_.gif") no-repeat right top;'>
                    <a href="/gp/associates/promo/buildlinks.html" style='float:left;background:url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/tab-unslected-left._V161554471_.gif") no-repeat left top;'>Links & Banners<span class="droparrow">&#x25BC;</span></a>

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="dropdownlinks">
            <div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/build-links/individual/main.html">Product Links</a></div><div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/build-links/banner/main.html">Banner Links</a></div><div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/build-links/text/main.html">Link to Any Page</a></div><div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/tools/link-checker/main.html">Link Checker</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>

                </li>


                <li style='background:url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/tab-unslected-right._V161557413_.gif") no-repeat right top;'>
                    <a href="http://widgets.amazon.in/?_encoding=UTF8&amp;store=httpswwwvanta-21&amp;tag=httpswwwvanta-21" style='float:left;background:url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/tab-unslected-left._V161554471_.gif") no-repeat left top;'>Widgets</a>
                </li>


                <li style='background:url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/tab-unslected-right._V161557413_.gif") no-repeat right top;'>
                    <a href="/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html" style='float:left;background:url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/tab-unslected-left._V161554471_.gif") no-repeat left top;'>Product Advertising API</a>
                </li>


                <li style='background:url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/tab-unslected-right._V161557413_.gif") no-repeat right top;'>
                    <a href="/gp/associates/network/reports/main.html" style='float:left;background:url("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/31/associates/network/08-ui-elements/tab-unslected-left._V161554471_.gif") no-repeat left top;'>Reports<span class="droparrow">&#x25BC;</span></a>


    <div class="parent"><div class="dropdownlinks">

    <div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/reports/report.html?ie=UTF8&amp;reportType=earningsReport" >Earnings Report</a>
</div><div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/reports/report.html?ie=UTF8&amp;reportType=ordersReport" >Orders Report</a>
</div><div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/reports/report.html?ie=UTF8&amp;reportType=linkTypeReport" >Link-Type Report</a>
</div><div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/reports/report.html?ie=UTF8&amp;reportType=trendsReport" >Daily Trends</a>
</div><div class="subitem"><a href="/gp/associates/network/reports/report.html?ie=UTF8&amp;reportType=tagsReport" >Tracking ID Summary Report</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
                </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
```

I am trying to select the "Earnings Report" from the dropdown menu.
I tried like this --

```
dropDownButton: WebElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@href='https://affiliate-program.amazon.in/gp/associates/network/reports/report.html?ie=UTF8&reportType=earningsReport']"))
dropDownButton.click()
```

I also tried like this --

```
val dropDownButton = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Earnings Report"))
dropDownButton.click()
```

In both the cases,  The code runs only when I hover my mouse over the dropdown menu. No manual click is required.

I also tried the following code which I am not sure if correct -

```
     import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
      def selectValueFromDropdown( value: String) = {
      var options = driver.findElements(By.id("menuh"));
      for(option <- options) {
            if (value.equals(option.getText())) {
                option.click()
            }
        }

      }

selectValueFromDropdown("Earnings Report")
```

I am kinda lost here. Please suggest a solution in either Java or Scala.

EDIT: I get to this page after log-in from the main page. Can that be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have to hover your mouse over the dropdown menu for it to work. Your menu also has sub-menus. So, before clicking the link you need to use the "perform" method of "Actions". In this manner it allows Selenium to spot a particular sub-menu while holding the menu. The code for that is:

```
val menuElement = driver.findElement(By.id("menuh"))
/* If the css selector used below does not match the element that
*  fires the hover action then check which element fires it and update
*  the selector */
val subMenuElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#menuh li:nth-child(5)"))
val earningsReportElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Earnings Report"))
val action = new Actions(driver)

action.moveToElement(menuElement).perform()
action.moveToElement(subMenuElement).perform()
action.moveToElement(earningsReportElement)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

Comment: This answer worked after re-arranging the statements .

Answer (score 3):

**Please try this:**

- First select the drop down and then select by value or Index-

`Select drpdown = new  Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Locator of the dropdown"));
drpdown.SelectByValue("Earning Report");`

- If "Earning Report" is a visible Text then-

`drpdown.selectByVisibleText("Earning Report");`

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
 driver.findElement(
            By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'earningsReport')]"))
            .click();
```

Comment: Nopes. Same result. As soon as I hover my mouse over the dropdown selector, the code executes. But, till than it just keeps waiting.

Comment: Just have a look whether this earnings report link is in different Iframe, if so you have to switch the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by @Dagojvg worked after re-arranging the expressions.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions
val action = new Actions(driver)
val menuElement = driver.findElement(By.id("menuh"))
action.moveToElement(menuElement).perform()

val subMenuElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#menuh li:nth-child(5)"))
action.moveToElement(subMenuElement).perform()

val earningsReportElement = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Earnings Report"))
action.moveToElement(earningsReportElement)

action.click()
action.perform()
```